# How to create multiline project pipeline to trigger manually both projects

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd

**Project Parent**

```
stages: 
 - build

build-project-test:
 stage: build
 when: manual
 trigger:
  project: /test-project
  branch: cicd-test
  strategy: depend
```

**test-project pipeline**

```
stages:
 - build

build-test-project:
 stage: build
 when: manual
 script:
  - mvn clean install
```

My question is test-project should trigger manually alone and also we should able to trigger test-project from other project like above.
above code is not working and giving error **i.e. down stream pipeline can't be created. Pipeline will not run for the selected trigger. the rules configuration prevented anu jobs from being added to the pipeline**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so with the following configuration on the `test-project` pipeline:

```
stages:
 - build

build-test-project:
  stage: build
  when: manual
  script:
    - mvn clean install
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"
    - when: manual
```

With these rules the job will be always manual besides the case when it will be triggered by [multi-project pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/index.html#configure-cicd-jobs-to-run-in-triggered-pipelines).